# Is there any mean to be notified at an end of jenkins build run (acknowledgment)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, continuous-integration

After some unluckily research, I would like to ask  here if there is any mean to do a simpe "end of build"  acknowledgement apart from emailing on jenkins.

Some tiers application needs **to know if a jenkins build run is finished** before this one allow another action to  be operated.
The restriction is that I do not have any rights to install some http plugin which for instance could allow to notify a webservice (which would have been a fit solution..... ).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you provide more information on "acknowledgement"? Can you make an API call for this?

Comment: I need to send an acknowledgment at the end of some build on jenkins... Indeed this "API Call" is basically was what I wanted  but I do not have any rights to install "HTTP" plugin on jenkins  thus cannot do any api call ...